# Gallery button not updating to current image it is meant to be associated with?

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, image-gallery

Ok I have made a gallery and it works ok apart from one thing 
If you click a navigation button when the animation is playing the navigation button will show the wrong highlighted button untill the image changes 
Here is an example of the problem:

http://puu.sh/gQkuv/600e32fa0d.mp4
and here is the js code and
JS fiddle:

```
  // gallery buttons
  $('.navi > img').click(function() {
    var sync = $(this).index();
    sync *= -galleryWidth;
    clearInterval(gallery);
    $('.pics > img').animate({'left': sync});
    $('.navi > img').removeClass('active');
    $('.navi > img:nth-of-type(' + ($(this).index() + 1) + ')').addClass('active');
    gallery = setInterval(autoplay(sync), 5000);
  });

  // gallery start loop
  var gallery = setInterval(autoplay(current), 5000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pa8pqnLw/2/

Sorry this isnt explained very good,
But can someone try to point out the problem and possible supply a solution.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your autoplay sets the dot after the animation is finished, when you click, it sets the dot right away and then it gets overridden by the complete function from autoplay

You need to stop the animation on click. I only edited this line in the navigation click handler by adding `.stop()`

```
$('.pics > img').stop().animate({'left': sync});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pa8pqnLw/4/

More info here https://api.jquery.com/stop/

> Description: Stop the currently-running animation on the matched
>   elements.